# Measuring thermal noise of RLC circuit

Tags: power-spectral-density, bandwidth

I am confused about [Johnson-Nyquist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise) noise. Specifically, where does bandwidth come in?

Thermal noise voltage is usually defined as something like: V^2=4kT∫R(f)df, integrated over a bandwidth.

I am trying to measure the thermal noise of a resistor in a parallel RLC circuit, in which the LC part acts as a narrow bandpass filter. In my case, I think this bandwidth is simply the FWHM of the LC circuit lorentzian resonance.

In order to get the correct value, should I integrate the power spectrum (PS) or Power Spectral Density, PSD = PS/((sampling rate/record length)*Equivalent Noise Power Window)? (The Equivalent Noise Power Window is related to the FFT windowing, e.g., applying a Hanning window to reduce spectral leakage, = 1.5.)

I am confused because a lot of the time the thermal noise is given as a PSD, i.e., in units of nV/rtHz. It seems like the sampling rate information needs to be removed in order to get the right number, but I can't find any literature that specifically explains this.

So, any help on the specifics of power spectral density, bandwidth, and thermal noise, in particular when dealing with an LC (bandpass filter) resonance, would be immensely helpful!

Comment: Are you trying to measure, or are you trying to calculate? If trying to measure, can you clarify what your complete set-up is and what you have done to overcome the thermal noise contributions of your measurement instrument? In either case, are you assuming a matched load impedance to get maximum power transfer?

Comment: I have a two stage low noise amplification chain connected to a parallel RLC circuit, the lc part acting as a narrow band pass filter for the thermal noise of the R. The first stage amplifier is cryogenic with an input voltage noise of <1 nV/rtHz. I’m trying to measure the Johnson noise of the effective total resistance of the RLC circuit at resonance, and was converting to PSD by dividing by the frequency resolution (and window parameter) of my ADC (spectrum analayzer.) However, my measured thermal noise is off by a factor of ~2 from what I expected to get. I’m assuming a matched load.

Comment: I can certainly help you but this belongs on the electronics StackExchange site. Can you move this there?

Comment: Definitely, will do! Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because user is posting this on the electronics StackExchange site.

Comment: Posted my question on the electronics StackExchange site [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/684702/how-to-properly-compute-noise-power-spectral-density).